# I want an object to be both animated and controlled by a motor

Tags: objects, constraints

I have an object (cube) that I have made an active rigid body. I connected a motor to it and it rotates when I have dynamic selected and animated unchecked.  If I check animate it will animate (I'm adjusting z location on the timeline) but it won't rotate by the motor. Unchecking dynamic has no effect when animate is checked.

I uploaded an [example file][1] that shows this issue. Is there a workaround or am I missing something? I can't seem to find any other questions like this. I am a noob though. Thanks.

[1]: [image]

Comment: your file needs an authorization  ;)

Comment: How do I get my file authorized?

Comment: I mean I can't donwload it, please use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Here ya go... file checked...